# file.exists() always false, when checking the drawables

Tags: android, file, drawable

I nearly spend the whole day to find a solution for the following problem:

```
Uri uri = Uri.parse("android.resource://de.test.app/" + R.drawable.ic_tab_artists_grey);
    File file2 = new File(uri.getPath());
    Boolean fileexists = file2.exists();
```

fileexists never retruns the value true. Is there any mistake?

Best regards

Samson

---

First of all thank You for the quick answers,

my Problem is that the following code

```
Intent myIntent = new Intent(android.content.Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
            myIntent.setData(Uri.parse("android.resource://de.test.app/" + R.drawable.ic_tab_artists_grey));
            myIntent.setType("image/png");
            startActivityForResult(myIntent, 1);
```

creates the Error:

```
Unable to start Activity ComponentInfo{com.android.gallery/com.android.camera.ViewImage}: java.lang.nullPointerException
```

and I thought this happens, because the file doesn't exsists. Is my setData path wrong?

Comment: Why are you checking if a drawable exists?  The drawable will always be included in your .apk

Comment: I want to test it for a kind of debugging, because I'm trying to open an image with the build in android image viewer, but every time there is an error, because a NullPointer is forwarded to the image viewer app.

Comment: Take a look at my answer, you can't substitute `R.drawable.ic_tab_artists_grey` for the filename.

Comment: you can edit your que rather than post is like ans

Answer (score 1):

When you search for a file, you can't use the ID from the R.java file.  `R.drawable.ic_tab_artists_grey` is just an android constant for a number representing an index for your drawable, and will not be a filename.

In any case, you shouldn't need to check whether a drawable exists or not.  Anything included in your drawable directory will get loaded alongside your application in the APK.